# Circle border-radius with a border outline only shows up as a square on page load?

Tags: html, css

I've created three circles that are used for the dot controls/pagination on an image slider. For some reason on page load in Chrome they always appear first as squares and not as circles. Once you interact with them they then turn to circles. How can I get them to be outlined circles on page load? (if i just fill in the circles with a background they work and are circles on page load but I want them to be outlined circles on page load)

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
.flex-control-paging li a {
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   margin: 0 8px;
   height: 8px;
   width: 8px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-border-radius: 50%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #b6b6b6;   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "once you interact with them"? Once you click on them? If setting a background works, can't you just set the background to the same colour as the page?

Comment: Provide us js && html code of slider creating

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys! I figured out what the issue was but I don't quite understand why. I added an overflow to the dots and this took care of the bordered showing up as a square rather than a circle like I wanted on page load.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do u mean.

But I think issue is html of slider creates dynamically via js on dom or page load event, so css applied with some delay.

Check source code of your page with right click->view source to ensure.

Try to call your slider plugin immediately after slider container, not at the end of page for ex.